# How to get the latency of an application deployed in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a simple java based application deployed in Kubernetes. I want to get the average latency of requests sent to the application(GET and POST).

[Stackdriver Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-loadbalancing) has the latency details of loadbalancer. But that can only be collected after 210 seconds which is not sufficient in my case. How can I configure in Kubernetes to get the latency details every 30 seconds (or 1 minute) **immediately**.

I wish the solution to be independent of Java so that I can use it for any application I deploy.

Comment: you could use e.g. Istio to measure that, but it is a more complex setup.

Comment: Is there any reference to set it up?

Comment: See my answere for reference to set it up

Answer (score 3):

On GKE, you can use [Stackdriver Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/java), which is GCP specific. I am currently fighting with python client library. Hopefully Java is more mature.

Or you can use [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/), which is CNCF project.

Comment: Is there any language independent solution?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you were looking for a language indepentend solution. In that case Istio, as the colleague is suggesting would be the way to go. And actually I disagree that the setup is more complex. You need to pass headers from one microservice to another and since Istio intercepts all calls through Envoy proxies, it will just automatically show the traces.

Comment: I have not worked with Istio before. Do you have any reference guide that I can follow to set up the latency monitoring?

Comment: I am sorry, I dont. This is from the official docs: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/jaeger/

Answer (score 2):

### Use a Service Mesh

A Service Mesh will let you **observe** things like latency between your services without extra code for this in each applications. [Istio](https://cloud.google.com/istio/) is such an implementation that is available on Google Kubernetes Engine.

> Get uniform metrics and traces from any running applications without requiring developers to manually instrument their applications.
>
> Istio’s monitoring capabilities let you understand how service performance impacts things upstream and downstream

See [Istio on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/)

> use a service mesh: software that helps you orchestrate, secure, and collect telemetry across distributed applications. A service mesh transparently oversees and monitors all traffic for your application, typically through a set of network proxies that sit alongside each microservice.

[Welcome to the service mesh era](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/welcome-to-the-service-mesh-era-introducing-a-new-istio-blog-post-series)

Comment: Being new to Istio, I find it bit difficult to understand how we can ask Istio to collect the latency

Comment: @anushiya-thevapalan you have to read about distributed tracing, but how to set this up is a different question. https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/